# How to Order by hierarchical CreatedOn when children may be null

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I looked through a few related questions on this, but haven't seen anything that quite matches what I need, so please bear with me.

I have 3 classes that are in a hierarchy:

```
public class Dialog {
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Response {
    public DateTime      CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public IList<Dialog> Dialogs   { get; set; }
}

public class Request{
    public DateTime        CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public IList<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

So basically, I'm displaying Requests, but I want to display them in the order of the most recent activity, whether that was on the Message, Response, or Dialog. Obviously, some Messages might not have Responses, and some Responses might not have Dialogs.

I'm using EntityFramework, but that's not necessarily related since this ordering could be on any hierarchical grouping that uses LINQ to order the objects.

Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
Requests.OrderByDescending(r => r.CreatedOn)
        .ThenByDescending(r => r.Offers.Any() ? r.Offers.Max(o => o.CreatedOn) : DateTime.MinValue)
        .ThenByDescending(r => r.Offers.SelectMany(o => o.Dialogs).Any() ? r.Offers.SelectMany(o => o.Dialogs).Max(d => d.CreatedOn) : DateTime.MinValue)
```

My question with this is that I think that wouldn't the subsequent `ThenByDescending`s override the previous, or am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there a way to find the Max CreatedOn in one Ordering between the Request and all of its decendants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing multiple orderings (which as you've said will destroy the previous ordering), you could get the max date for each list, then get the max (maxest?) date of tem all.

If you were at least guaranteed to have empty `Response` and `Dialogs` lists, you could get the max date like this:

```
 var r = req.OrderByDescending(x => new[]
 {
     x.CreatedOn,
     x.Responses.Select(y => y.CreatedOn).Max(),
     x.Responses.Select(y => y.Dialogs.Select(z => z.CreatedOn).Max()).Max()
 }.Max()).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

If the values could be null, then you could create a new list in the query. If you're feeding this directly to EF to query the database, it may not work... I don't have anywhere to test it right now.

```
var r = req.OrderByDescending(x => new[]
{
    x.CreatedOn,
    (x.Responses ?? new List<Response>()).Select(y => y.CreatedOn).Max(),
    (x.Responses ?? new List<Response>()).Select(y => (y.Dialogs ?? new List<Dialog>())
                                .Select(z => z.CreatedOn).Max()).Max()
}.Max()).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

**EDIT by OP**

I had to make a few changes to get this to compile. As it was based on this answer, the kudos go to Grant Winney.

```
var results = req.OrderByDescending(r => new[] { // Create a new array to hold the dates.
                r.CreatedOn, // Start with the date of the Request
                (r.Offers.Any() ? 
                    r.Offers.Select(o => o.CreatedOn).Max() : // If the Request has any Offers, get the max date of the offers.
                    DateTime.MinValue), // Otherwise add Min value so it won't affect the results.
                (r.Offers.Any() ?
                    r.Offers.Select(o => o.Dialogs.Any() ? // If each Offer from each Request have any Dialogs
                        o.Dialogs.Select(d => d.CreatedOn).Max() : // Get the Max Dialog Date for each Offer
                        DateTime.MinValue) // Or put in a Min value for each Offer.
                    .Max() : // Then find the max for reach Offer's Dialogs (or Min Value for each Offer)
                    DateTime.MinValue) // If there are no Offers, again use Min value.
              }.Max()) // Then get the Max from the 3 values in the array.
              .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: I had to change the syntax around to get this to compile. With it compiled, all of my Unit Tests that I had set up to test the ordering still work. Would you mind if I appended an edit to the bottom?

Comment: Just some syntax changes to get it to compile.

Comment: Doing that array in the OrderBy was something that I hadn't seen before, and found it very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind changing your model, perhaps you could make it like this:

```
public class Dialog {
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Response {
  public DateTime      CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public IList<Dialog> Dialogs   { get; set; }

  public DateTime MaxDateTime {
    get {
      if (Dialogs == null) return CreatedOn;

      var max = Dialogs.Max(o => o.CreatedOn);
      return CreatedOn >= max ? CreatedOn : max;
    }
  }
}

public class Request{
  public DateTime        CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public IList<Response> Responses { get; set; }

  public DateTime MaxDateTime {
    get {
      if (Responses == null) return CreatedOn;

      var max = Responses.Max(o => o.MaxDateTime);
      return CreatedOn >= max ? CreatedOn : max;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could do the ordering simply by sorting the `MaxDateTime` property.

```
var orderedRequests = requests.OrderByDescending(o => o.MaxDateTime);
```

Comment: I wish I could rate this higher more than once for it's simplicity. I wouldn't really consider this a "change" to the model, more an addition to as none of the existing functionality needs to be altered to get it to work. Nice job!

Comment: Though, now that I think about it a little more, because of the fact that I would be running this against a LINQ to Entities query, and not an in-memory collection, this won't work for what I'm trying to do with it. I do still love it for how easily it will work for in-memory though.